# looking to improve qaulity for video output

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-encoding, latency, rtmp

For the last 5 years I have been streaming a live stream 24/7 from a streaming studio which requires low latency rtmp output to a web based player client.
I am using vMix to capture my sdi signal from the camera and ffmpeg to encode and publish the rtmp stream to the origin server.
The low latency necessity (3 seconds glass to glass) require me to use ultrafast encoding that effects the video quality.
I am not happy with the results for a while now and been thinking that maybe the community can assist me to find ways to improve the quality of the stream, either because I have set the commands wrong or maybe there has been new features in the last 5 years I am not aware of.
I will appreciate any input you could provide.
The current command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg.exe -async 2 -report -rtbufsize 256M -f dshow -i "video=vMix Video:audio=vMix Audio" -codec:v libx264 -r 25 -tune fastdecode -tune zerolatency -s:v 1280x720 -pix_fmt:v yuv420p -threads 4 -bufsize:v 1000k -g:v 50 -preset:v ultrafast -profile:v Main -level:v 3.0 -b:v 2500k -maxrate:v 2700k -flush_packets 1 -codec:a libfaac -b:a 64k -strict -2 -rtmp_flashver "FMLE/3.0 (compatible; vMix/15.0.0.74)" -f flv rtmp://address/live/StreamName
```

I am using HP Z440 with windows 10 pro as the publisher PC, with vMix version 21.
The video signal input is 720p/50p coming from a pxw-z90 camera and cut to 25p in the output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is way beyond my expertise, but if you don't get answers in a couple of days here, I'd think about asking for it to be migrated to https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ThanksTetsujin, How do I ask that?

Comment: You should be able to see a 'flag' option just below your post. Click, 'flag for a mod' & ask in the text box. Wish you luck. [After it's migrated you'll have to Join that stack too, I don't think it's automatic.] btw, if you need to reply to any specific person on a comment thread, use @theirname  otherwise they might miss it. Thread author is always notified, but comments don't unless specified.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you!

Comment: Welcome:) Wish you luck. [Somebody may tidy up these comments as part of the migration, comments are ephemeral & used for clarification. Once they've served their purpose, they can go bye-bye ;))

Comment: First step is to [download](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) a modern `ffmpeg`. Yours is at least 5 years old given that it is using libfaac. Then show the complete log from your command using the new version.

Comment: @llogan, is there any difference in the command syntax between the current version and the new `ffmpeg` version you directed me to?

Comment: @llogan done what you suggested, but I don't see how I can attach or copy the log in the comment (too long).

Comment: @TLM It's best to [edit] your question to add such info.